# Netlogo Lists: detecting the patch in a list with max distance to one specific patch - for each turtle

Tags: list, netlogo

I want to solve a problem in Netlogo that so far exceeds my programming skills. I want to built a list for each turtle which contains the furthest patch the turtle went on this "day". So far I tried to built a list were all patches are stored for each turtle. Now I want to calculate - for each turtle - the patch from this list that has maximum distance from its home (hide). I want to empty the list every night (thats not mandatory) Thats my code so far:

```
let temp-visited-patch-list lput patch-here temp-visited-patch-list
  if period = night
  [ 
    [foreach [temp-visited-patch-list] [x ->  set visited-patch-list lput (max x [distance hide]) visited-patch-list]]
    let temp-visited-patch-list []
]
```

So I am not that far to extract the values for each turtle seperatly - and even the part I posted does not work. I get an "expected command" error. I would be very thankful for any suggestions to solve this problem.
Best regards
Olivia

Comment: is there a specific reason you need a list? There are much easier ways to conceptualise this. Instead of storing the list then processing it at night and deleting it, if all you care about is the maximum distance, just calculate the distance to the hide as it wanders around and keep that value it if it's bigger than the previous stored value

Comment: Hi JenB, I don´t need the list - but I need the patch with the max distance to the hide for each turtle seperate - and I thought this info would be easy (so far I am not entirely sure how) to extract from the list :) I want to calculate homeranges for every turtel in the simulation. I also had the idea to wotk with agentsets instead of lists but there I have the problem that for calculation I would mix patch and turtle variables - Netlog is not happy about this...

Comment: Each turtle has its own value of the variable. Just like some turtles can be green and some can be blue - this is what `turtles-own` is for. So turtle 1 would know it went say 5, and turtle 2 would know it went say 4 etc.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you want to tell me. I need the furthest patch (not the distance, the patch) that each trutle went in relation to its hide. This patch should be stored in al list for every turtle seperately, so that I can calculate minimum convex hull/polygon for the homeranges. How can I do this with turtles-own? Maybe you could add a bit of code that makes it easier to understand for me how you would tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code has the turtles move, remember their furthest patch and turns those patches red and calculates average distance. It should help orient you how to use patches and turtle attributes to solve your question.

```
globals [home-patch]

turtles-own
[ farpatch
  maxdistance
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set home-patch one-of patches
  ask home-patch
  [ set pcolor blue
    sprout 20
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  repeat 20 [movement]
  ask (patch-set [farpatch] of turtles) [set pcolor red]
  type "Average max distance:" print mean [maxdistance] of turtles
  tick
end

to movement
  ask turtles
  [ set heading random 360
    forward 1
    if distance home-patch > maxdistance
    [ set maxdistance distance home-patch
      set farpatch patch-here
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - but if I change this ONE home-patch to the circumstances I work with I again just go down the rabbit hole encountering problems with agents, agentsets and lists - DSTANCE for example does not work with agentsets - just with one agent (patch). I need a solution for lists (or agentsets) containing PATCHES and somehow find out the patch of the list for each turtle that is the farthest from the respective hide. most primitives don´t work under this circumstances. Maby I just think to complicated - I am open for other solutions that give me the same resutls...

Comment: of course you can't find the distance to an agentset - think about the logic, what are you asking the turtle to find the distance to if there's say 5 agents in the agentset? The closest agent or the middle of the 5 agents or something else? And the example code I gave you stores a patch in the variable farpatch - that's not a number or some other data type, it is a patch

Comment: Hi JenB, if you are able to solve the problem I have via code for exactly this problem - I would kindly ask you to help. Just telling me what does not work unfortunately doesn´t solve anything. My problem is exactly that I have to find a solution for calculating homeranges - that it does not work the way tried I already found out as you know. But the solution you offered via your code also does not solve my problem. I am able to store variabels in patches. But unfortunately I have to find a solution that works with more than one patch- thats what I ask for.

Comment: I have tried to help but you have not explained your problem in a way that I can understand what it is that doesn't work. The code I have already provided exactly creates the set of patches that I thought you wanted - each turtle contributes one patch to the set, the patch furthest away that it reached (that's the patches the turn red).